# One handler for multiple plots in R (without ggplot)

Tags: r, plot, handler

I have a function which plots 4 graphs based on a data file, each in distinct page of a `pdf` file. Currently, I need to get one handler for all of them, I mean I prefer my function returns a handler for all these graphs instead of saving them as a `pdf` file. Is it possible?

It should be noted that I use `plot(.)`, not `ggplot2`.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "handle" and "hander"? Base graphics function do not return objects; they draw directly to the current graphics device.

Comment: As it stands it's kind of hard to tell what you're asking. Please include a [minimum reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to show what you've tried and what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep your plotting function and its arguments separate, e.g.:

```
do_plot <- function(formula, dat) {
    plot(formula, data=dat)
    # other plotting commands go here
} 

handle <- list(
  fun=do_plot, 
  arg=list(formula="Sepal.Length~Sepal.Height", data=iris)
)
```

To actually plot, you would then use `do.call`:

```
do.call(handle$fun, handle$arg)
```